How to make Google Auth refresh token wont expired? (Gmail API)
I need to use Postman for testing, which includes reading Gmail content and deleting specific emails. However, my refresh token expires after 7 days, even though I have switched my app status from "Testing" to "Published." This doesn't seem to resolve the issue. Could it be related to the scope settings? I need to use https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify rather than some basic scope, and i see someone said this could be a problem.
Alternatively, is there a way to automate the refresh token renewal process? Currently, I have to manually use the folloing URL https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=Your_ClientID&redirect_uri=http://localhost&scope=https://mail.google.com/&response_type=code&access_type=offline&prompt=consent to generate a response code for getting new refresh token
I have switched my app status from "Testing" to "Published but still have to get new Google Auth refresh token after 7 days.

I think you should check to be sure you are using the correct client.  Once you set your app to published the refresh token will stop expiring.   If its still expiring you haven't switched it.

If you use Postman's OAuth 2.0 helper, you should be able to auto-refresh your access tokens easily.
This article walks you through that process and includes a video on YouTube that covers the same.
